# Adding custom headers in dotnet core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have developed a service using DotNet core web api. We need to have custom headers returned with some data for all the requests. we have developed a middleware for returning the custom header. 
It is working as expected when we are trying to fetch the service via source code (executing the api via visual studio and accessing the service using postman). However when we deploy the service in the DEV environment where we are accessing the services via HTTPS, none of the services are returning the custom header.

we have enabled the cors as follows in startup.cs:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();

            }));

app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

and included the following in before adding the header in middleware:

```
headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "pickup-claims");
```

Are we missing any settings?

Comment: Please add your middleware code and where you call `app.UserYourMiddleware`

Comment: the order of service registration as well as order of application builder statements may vary for the execution. Please share your startup.cs